# How to integrate the normal distribution

Tags: probability

I want to find $E(|X-\mu|)$ where $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. I know this is equal to $$2\int_{-\infty}^\mu |x-\mu| \,\,{1\over \sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\,\exp(-(x-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2)\,dx$$ but I am unsure as to how to calculate this integral.

Comment: I think you lucked out. After dispensing appropriately with absolute values, you can integrate by substitution.

Comment: Not that it matters, but I would prefer saying it is twice the integral from $\mu$ to infinity. Positive is nice.

Comment: I agree. That's what I meant by appropriately. See below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: start with $Z\sim N(0,1)$, use symmetry
and $u=\frac12x^2,~du=x\,dx$:
$$\def\E{\mathbb{E}}
\E\left[|Z|\right]
=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty|x|\,e^{-x^2/2}\,dx
=\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\int_0^\infty x\,e^{-x^2/2}\,dx
=\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-u}\,du
=\sqrt{\frac2\pi}$$
Thus for $X=\mu +\sigma Z$,
$$\E\left[|X-\mu|\right]
=\sigma\,\E\left[|Z|\right]
=\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\,\sigma.$$

Comment: You want $|x|$, not $x$, in your first integral.